# Removing outline color from only one layer in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a graph consisting of three layers (violin, box and beeswarm plots) using  the following

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggbeeswarm)

df <- data.frame(var1 = sample(c("Condition A", "Condition B"), 50, replace =T),
   var2 = sample(c("Group 1", "Group 2"), 50, replace =T),
   value = sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 50, replace =T))

ggplot(df, aes(x=var1, y=value, fill = var2, group = interaction(var1,var2))) +
  geom_violin(position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(0.8), width = .6, outlier.shape = NA) +
  # from ggbeeswarm
  geom_quasirandom(method = "pseudorandom", dodge.width=0.8, size = 3, alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=alpha(c("#848484","#0F185B"), .3)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#848484","#0F185B")) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text = element_text(size=15))
```

The plot looks 
[like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YElgj.png)
However, I wanted the violins to be simple shaded areas below the boxplots, i.e. with a transparent fill, but no outline, so that the lines of the boxes and violins don't clash and the graph is easier to look at.

My problem is that I don't know how to set the alpha for `color` to zero *only* in this specific layer (`geom_violin()`) while keeping the outlines of the other layers visible. `scale_color_manual` affects all `geom` layers equally, so if I set alpha to zero there, then the boxes and dots lose their outlines, which I don't want. `geom_violin` does have an `alpha` argument, but this affects only the `fill` color's transparency, so that doens't solve the problem either.

[This is what I want to achieve*.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddCs6.png) (*Note that I used [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) to remove the outlines manually.)

In general, I would like to know whether it is possible to set different alpha values for `fill` and `color` for different layers of the same plot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a call to make color = NA in the geom_violin line.

```
geom_violin(position = position_dodge(0.8), color = NA)
```

[image]